# update query is not working - mysql

Tags: mysql

Following is my table structure:

```
+------+----------+
| product   | seq |
+------+----------+
|    a      | 1   |
|    b      | 1   |
|    a      | 2   |
|    a      | 3   |
|    b      | 2   |
+------+----------+
```

If my inputs are `a` and `2` then, i need to change the sequence number and the  the output will be

```
+------+----------+
| product   | seq |
+------+----------+
|    a      | 2   |
|    b      | 1   |
|    a      | 1   |
|    a      | 3   |
|    b      | 2   |
+------+----------+
```

am using the logic as :

```
update mytable SET seq=if(seq=2,1,2), seq=if(seq=1,2,1) where product='a'
```

But it will not make any changes in the table

Comment: and your question is ... ?

Comment: Query will not give any change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
UPDATE table1 s1 , table1 s2 SET s1.seq=s2.seq, 
s2.seq=s1.seq WHERE s1.seq=2 and s2.seq=1 and
s1.product='a' and s2.product='a';
```